# How do I tag another user in a Question/Answer in recognition for their inspiration?

Tags: discussion, markdown

I can tag a user in a *Comment*, but I can't find how to specifically tag a user in a *Question* or *Answer*

> *"Why would you want to do that instead of just doing it in a Comment?"*

...you may ask?

I want to give them recognition for something they wrote which inspired, *but which is not the same as*, my *Question* or *Answer*.

The syntax for tagging users in *Comments* doesn't work in *Questions*/*Answers*, so:

- ***How do I tag users in Questions and Answers?***

Comment: Do you want to notify the users or just mention them?

Answer (score 11):

You can add a link in your post to their user profile, or better yet, the post that inspired your answer.  If your post is derived from theirs, linking their post also satisfies the [attribution requirement](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) of the [CC-BY-SA license](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) that applies to all Stack Overflow content.

So for instance, if I wrote a post that was derived from this post, and I wanted to credit you, I could add to my post:

```
This is based on [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400069/how-do-i-tag-another-user-in-a-question-answer-in-recognition-for-their-inspirat) by [skeetastax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4898202/skeetastax).
```

which would render as:

> This is based on [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400069/how-do-i-tag-another-user-in-a-question-answer-in-recognition-for-their-inspirat) by [skeetastax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4898202/skeetastax).

Note that this doesn't notify the user directly, but it does credit them for the inspiration, and might inspire people to go to the post and upvote it if they find it useful as well.

Comment: Linking to their post also adds a record to the Linked Posts, shown at the right of the page. Valuable content gets a better exposure this way.Only linking to a user profile would not achieve the same effect.

Comment: Note that you can also click the "share" link under the post in question to get a slightly less cumbersome URL. Delete the last grouping of numbers for more privacy (e.g., the share link for this answer, for me, brings up https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400072/215552, but it would work just as well as https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400072).